# After call jobFinished(mParams, false) why the job is still pending?

Tags: android, android-jobscheduler

After I call `jobFinished(mParams, false)` I can see that the **job is still pending** because when I do `getPendingJob` just after I can still see the job.

When the job is finished I would like to schedule a new job, but I can't because `getPendingJob` say the job is still running and if I do `jobScheduler.schedule` then it's will stop the currently job running (don't know if it's matter)

*NOTE*: The main problem by cancelling the currently job running will be to have the event `onStopJob(JobParameters params)` to be called. and this is really problematic

this is the code of jobFinished **implemented in android** if it's can help someone to understand

```
public final void jobFinished(JobParameters params, boolean needsReschedule) {
    ensureHandler();
    Message m = Message.obtain(mHandler, MSG_JOB_FINISHED, params);
    m.arg2 = needsReschedule ? 1 : 0;
    m.sendToTarget();
}
```

so of course it's seam that jobFinished will simply send a message that will be processed in the looper (in next loop), so before I go out of the current loop the jobFinished  will not be processed :( how can I do in such way ?

Comment: Is that method from a JobService? You shouldn't override jobFinished, you should just call it when the service is done. Please post your entire JobService code, if you can.

Comment: yes this method if from jobservice, I just wrote it like a documentation, I do not override it

Comment: The JobService is a bound service, so when it is finished/canceled by JobSchedulerService, the onUnbind method from Service is called. Theoretically, you could reschedule it there.
Why do you need to reschedule it? And why in the JobService?